# WordPress - New wp-login URL

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, admin, request-uri

I want to change the `wp-login.php` url. Got most of it working:

```
if(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == 'theadmin'){
    include ABSPATH . '/wp-login.php';
    exit; 
}
```

But the form submits to `wp-login.php`. I don't want to copy the full `wp-login.php`, because WordPress core might change in the future, and so does that file.

Is there any way to get the code working properly, so the errors appear and submits to `/theadmin`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @StephenRauch There is already a minimal, complete and verifiable example included..... there isn't anything more I can give you